# Calculating $S_n$ ($k$th) statistic

Tags: calculus, statistics, discrete-mathematics

I am having difficulty solving/completing the following equation using inputs $\{1,2,3,5,6,7\}$:

$Q_n = C_n\cdot\{|X_i-X_j|;i < j\}_{(k)}$

$C_n = 2.2219$

$(k)$ = $k$th order statistic

So far I have the following:

```
    7 6 5 3 2 1
1   6 5 4 2 1 
2   5 4 3 1 
3   4 3 2 
5   2 1 
6   1  
7
```

How would you obtain a final value of $Q_n$?

Comment: Looks like you need to first determine $k$, then find that order statistic. According to [NIST](http://www.itl.nist.gov/div898/software/dataplot/refman2/auxillar/diffqn.htm) one should choose $k = {h \choose 2}$ where $h = [\frac n2] + 1$. Since $n=6$ in your problem then $h = 4$, so $k = {4 \choose 2} = 6$. Do you have a reference you are working from?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the comment. From what you have said wouldn't k = 2 not 6? Also, for reference -  https://www.researchgate.net/publication/221996720_Alternatives_to_Median_Absolute_Deviation

Comment: Honestly, I am so confused by the equation. Is there any way you can show me a step by step how to solve this formula based on the inputs   {1,2,3,5,6,7}?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As requested, here is the problem done out in steps.

1. Start with data, $\{X_1,\ldots, X_n\}$, which is in this case $\{1,2,3,5,6,7\}$, so $n=6$.
2. Form the (multi)set of differences $$\{|X_i-X_j|; i < j\} = \{1,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,4,4,4,5,5,6\}$$ (write the elements in increasing order for convenience).
3. Calculate $k = 6$. To do this, use $k = {h \choose 2}$ where $h = [\frac n2] + 1$. Since $n=6$ then $h = 4$ and $$k = {h \choose 2} = {4 \choose 2} = \frac{4!}{2!\cdot 2!} = \frac {24}4 = 6.$$
4. Since $k=6$, find the 6th order statistic of the multiset of differences, $\{|X_i-X_j|; i < j\}_{(6)}$. This is just the 6th largest element:
   $$\{1,\,1,\,1,\,1,\,2,\,2,\,2,\,3,\,3,\fbox{4},\require{cancel}\cancel{4},\require{cancel}\cancel{4},\require{cancel}\cancel{5},\require{cancel}\cancel{5},\require{cancel}\cancel{6}\}$$ so in this case it is 4.
5. Multiply by scaling constant $C_n$ which is 2.2219 (apparently doesn't depend on $n$, although for other estimators maybe the scale depends on $n$).
   $$Q_n = 2.2219\cdot4 = 8.8876.$$

(*Please note:* I'm not a statistician, I'm just following instructions. It could be I misunderstood some of the notation.)

Comment: Thank you so much! It all makes sense now!